# Why Are Mining Passwords 'x'

Tags: security, mining

In any of the 'get started mining' type sites, I see that password is always x. In xmr-stak, it seems to suggest putting in 'mostly empty or x' as a password. Does this really mean I should be using some default one-character password, or am I just misreading?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Unfortunately I can only pick one as 'the' answer, though I'd probably take all three that have as of yet been written if I could. To support decentralization, I think I'll give it to the answerer with the least rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'x' is just a placeholder. It is up to the pool to decide how to use it. It is just an optional message that could be passed between a miner and a pool. For example, often pools allow miners to use it to assign individual workers names/IDs.

Answer (score 2):

It's a placeholder, since they're unused (or, at least, I am not aware of any mining software which uses that password), even though they're part of the JSON communication between miner and pool. You can put whatever you like, x or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

They're used to login to the pool's UI, usually if it's an email address the pool will also email you alerts regarding the status of the worker.